# Does roboflow tool annotate the images correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, roboflow

I have started working Helmet Detection problem and decided to train the YOLO model. The very first step is to get a good quality dataset, which I found here on [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/andrewmvd/helmet-detection). The total number of images is 756 in number with their XML files that represent the images. I have decided to add more images and corresponding annotations to the respective `images` and `annotations` folders. I  have started using `roboflow` to annotate the images from the web. After downloading two images with their `XML` annotation, I simply run the following `python3 script` to check whether the `XML` annotation is correctly positioned or not.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from PIL import Image
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Load your image
# image = Image.open('/home/anil/Pictures/Screenshots/BikesHelmets767.png')
image = Image.open('/home/anil/Downloads/Helmet/archive/images/BikesHelmets3.png')
# image = Image.open('/home/anil/Downloads/BikesHelmets766.png')

# Parse the XML content
xml_content = '''Your XML code'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml_content)

# Extract bounding boxes and labels
boxes = []
for obj in root.findall('object'):
    label = obj.find('name').text
    bndbox = obj.find('bndbox')
    xmin = int(bndbox.find('xmin').text)
    ymin = int(bndbox.find('ymin').text)
    xmax = int(bndbox.find('xmax').text)
    ymax = int(bndbox.find('ymax').text)
    boxes.append({'label': label, 'bbox': (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)})

# Plot the image
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(image)

# Plot each bounding box
for box in boxes:
    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = box['bbox']
    rect = patches.Rectangle((xmin, ymin), xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin, linewidth=1, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
    ax.add_patch(rect)
    plt.text(xmin, ymax, box['label'], color='white', verticalalignment='bottom', bbox={'color': 'red', 'pad': 0})

plt.show()
```

Where `xml_content` I use the `XML` code. But what I realize the bounding boxes are not correctly annotated on the images.
[image]

But the `XML` code from the Kaggle data set correctly put the bounding boxes on the corresponding images from the Kaggle data set by using the same `python3 script`
[image]

I am skeptical about the `roboflow`. Please kindly correct me if I am doing something wrong. Thanks.